# Principle range of object orientation using image moments

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to extract the angle of a shape in my image using moments in opencv/c++. I am able to extract the angle, but the issue is that the principal range of this angle is 180 degrees. This makes the orientation of the object ambiguous with respect to 180 degree rotations. The code I am using to extract the angle currently is,

```
findContours(frame, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

vector<vector<Point2i> > hull(contours.size());

int maxArea = 0;
int maxI = -1;

int M20 = 0;
int M02 = 0;
int M11 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    convexHull(contours[i], hull[i], false);
    approxPolyDP(hull[i], contourVertices, arcLength(hull[i], true)*0.1, true);
    shapeMoments = moments(hull[i], false);

    if(shapeMoments.m00 <= areaThreshold || shapeMoments.m00 >= MAX_AREA)
        continue;

    if(contourVertices.size() <= 3 || contourVertices.size() >= 7)
        continue;

    if(shapeMoments.m00 >= maxArea)
    {
        maxArea = shapeMoments.m00;
        maxI = i;
    }
}

if(maxI == -1)
    return false;

fabricContour = hull[maxI];

approxPolyDP(hull[maxI], contourVertices, arcLength(hull[maxI], true)*0.02,true);
shapeMoments = moments(hull[maxI], false);
centerOfMass = Point2f(shapeMoments.m10/shapeMoments.m00, shapeMoments.m01/shapeMoments.m00);

drawContours(contourFrame, hull, maxI, Scalar(24, 35, 140), CV_FILLED, CV_AA);
drawContours(originalFrame, hull, maxI, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 8, CV_AA);
circle(contourFrame, centerOfMass, 4, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 10, 8, 0);

posX = centerOfMass.x;
posY = centerOfMass.y;
M11 = shapeMoments.mu11/shapeMoments.m00;
M20 = shapeMoments.mu20/shapeMoments.m00;
M02 = shapeMoments.mu02/shapeMoments.m00;
num = double(2)*M11;
den = M20 - M02;
angle = (int(-1*(180/(2*M_PI))*atan2(num, den)) + 45 + 180)%180;
//angle = int(-1*(180/(2*M_PI))*atan2(num, den));

area = shapeMoments.m00;
```

Is there any way I can remove the ambiguity from this extracted angle? I tries using the third order moments, but they do not seem to be very reliable.